# Convert Actionscript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, comparison, flash, converters

I was just wondering is there anyway to convert Actionscript to Javascript. When I say Actionscript I mean Actionscript 3. I've used google swiffy but Actionscript 3 is hardly supported. I've also heard of Jangaroo but its not what I want. Even if its a code comparison! Thanks!

Comment: The languages are not so different, but the APIs are completely different.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript and ActionScript (especially AS3) are syntactically similar languages and both are based on the ECMAScript Specification. There are some small differences in the actual code such as:

```
//Actionscript:
var a:String = new PlayerName();

//JavaScript:
var a = new PlayerName();
```

This is a demonstration that JavaScript does not have explicit variable type declarations, but this is not the real problem.

What you're asking goes much further than syntactic incompatibilities, as JS and AS work with completely different APIs. ActionScript has stages, frames and other *Flash-based* things which do not exist in JavaScript's environment. JavaScript - usually running in a browser - is used to manipulate documents, DOM nodes and CSS properties.

This means that unless you're just doing simple function calls and mathematics (without any dependency on the user or their environment) the things your program is doing simply cannot be transferred to another environment. For example, **you cannot tell JavaScript to `play()` or `goToAndStop()` because there are no frames to play, stop or go to in a HTML document.**

Unfortunately, I think what you're wondering is valid, but the question is almost certainly incorrect. If you have an application created in Flash or any other AS-enabled environment, you probably want to think about *porting* or *re-writing* it to the new context.

Comment: Not sure about the "especially AS3" bit. AS1 was more similar to JavaScript than AS3, and AS2 at least as similar to JavaScript as AS3 is, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at Falcon JS: https://github.com/apache/flex-falcon

Comment: Thanks, i'm sorry but im new to all of this programming stuff so I have no idea how to use it. If could explain how it will be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: That repo is empty today. Can you provide a new link?

Answer (score -2):

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=172
Just check it out the above. It might be useful.